# Configuring Spring boot Docker and Mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot and Docker.

I am trying to create a Spring Boot application connecting to mysql and using Docker to run both.

**Steps I followed**
*Step1* - Created mysql image and started running it.

```
docker run --name=docker-mysql --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root" --env="MYSQL_PASSWORD=root" --env="MYSQL_DATABASE=test" mysql
```

*Step2* Created a SpringBoot application

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t gradle-springboot-docker .
```

*Step3* Ran the Spring Boot app and linked with Mysql

```
docker run -t --name gradle-springboot-docker --link docker-mysql:mysql -p 8080:8080 gradle-springboot-docker
```

It gives basic connection error to mysql. I have listed the below application.properties. Is my connection information correct since I am using Docker. What would be the host for mysql?

```
SSL properties
server.port=8080

#DataSource
datasource.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test? 
autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false            
datasource.username=root
datasource.password=root

# Hibernate
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.lazy = true
hibernate.max_fetch_depth = 3
hibernate.packagesToScan = com.springboot.poc
# Once DB is created change below property to 'update'
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the container name of mysql as the hostname, since these are linked the mysql container is discoverable by its name from spring. So you need to change `datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?` to `datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql:3306/test?`

Or you can use the alias, as @g00glen00b suggested, like: `datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/test?`

Comment: FYI, he can also use the alias, so since he used `--link docker-mysql:mysql`, he can use either `docker-mysql` or `mysql` as the host name.

Comment: @g00glen00b, ah yes, i forgot that. Thank you :) I have added it to the answer